# Inserting duplicates while merging the tables in Oracle triggers

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have two tables, say test and books. My task is to create an Oracle trigger which will avoid/prevent duplicates while merging the test to books. No error but duplicates are inserting

**My tables :**

```
books: book_id(PK), book_name, author, no_of_copies
test : book_id, book_name, author, no_of_copies, CMT
```

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_books_edit
BEFORE INSERT ON books
REFERENCING NEW AS N 
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
WHEN ((select count(*) from books where book_name = N.book_name and author = N.Author) > 0)
BEGIN
    rollback; 
END 

**MERGE STAMTEMENT**

Merge the test to books and remove the duplicates of book_name and author 
rows from test to books

MERGE INTO books AS b 
USING (select book_id, book_name, author, no_of_copies from test where book_id >= 12) AS t
ON b.book_id = t.book_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET no_of_copies = b.no_of_copies + t.no_of_copies
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (book_id, book_name, author, no_of_copies)
    VALUES (t.book_id, t.book_name, t.author, t.no_of_copies);



Result :Trigger is not invoking and duplicates are inserting in books table.
```

Comment: If possible, you should use a unique index to prevent duplicates.

Comment: If you would want to merge records, then why use a trigger, you could use a MERGE statement to achieve this. Please provide more details about your requirement.

Comment: When you use MERGE statement, what kind of errors are having? You might want to update your question and title, otherwise either question will be closed or will be down marked.

Comment: I have changed the question and  body. I am not getting any errors but duplicates are inserting. I want a trigger which will not allow the duplicates while merging is happening between two tables. EOD, my goal is to see my table with unique values of bookname and author..

Comment: @user3454735 Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482167/trigger-to-check-for-duplicates), see this is helpful or not.

Comment: 1. Triggers cannot be used to enforce uniqueness. 2. Triggers cannot be used to enforce uniqueness. 3. Triggers cannot ROLLBACK (although they can raise exceptions which would cause a rollback). 4. Triggers cannot be used to enforce uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Create one new table something like books_and_test (with fields you don't want to duplicate), add unique index on multiple fields...
In trigger on books, test(trigger for each table) add statement before insert on books,test  insert values into books_and_test with catch exception on unique index violation. When there will be duplicated then do something you want in exception or nothing... 
This works but maybe there is better solution...
Better avoid triggers and try to search for constraint with function to check on duplicates in function..